# add computed column to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, export-to-csv

I expect that this don't be a classic beginner question. However I read and spent days trying to save my csv data without success.

I have a function that uses an input parameter that I give manually. The function generates 3 columns that I saved in a CSV file. When I want to use the function with other inputs and save the new data allocated at right from the previous computed columns, the result is that pandas  sort my CSV file in 3 single columns one below each other with the headings.

I'm using the next code to save my data:

```
data.to_csv('/Users/Computer/Desktop/Examples anaconda/data_new.csv', sep=',',mode='a')
```

and the result is:

```
dot  lake     mock
1      42    11.914558
2      41    42.446977
3      40    89.188668
dot  lake     mock    
1      42    226.266513
2      41    317.768887
dot  lake     mock
3      42    560.171830
4.     41.   555.005333
```

What I want is:

```
     dot  lake      mock        mock       mock
    0      42     11.914558. 226.266513. 560.171830
    1      41     42.446977. 317.768887. 555.005533
    2      40     89.188668
```

UPDATE:
My DataFrame was generated using a function like this:

First I opened a csv file:

```
df1=pd.read_csv('current_state.csv')


def my_function(df1, photos, coords=['X', 'Y']):


        Hzs = t.copy()
        shifts = np.floor(Hzs / t_step).astype(np.int)
        ms = np.zeros(shifts.size)
        delta_inv = np.arange(N+1)
        dot = delta_inv[N:0:-1]
        lake = np.arange(1,N+1)


        for i, shift in enumerate(shifts):
            diffs = df1[coords] - df1[coords].shift(-shift)
            sqdist = np.square(diffs).sum(axis=1)
            ms[i] = sqdist.sum()
            mock = np.divide(ms, dot)


        msds = pd.DataFrame({'dot':dot, 'lake':lake, 'mock':mock})
        return msds

data = my_function(df1, photos, coords=['X', 'Y'])

print(data)        

data.to_csv('/Users/Computer/Desktop/Examples anaconda/data_new.csv', sep=',',mode='a'
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is in how `pandas` writes to csv. You should show your code on how you build the `DataFrame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for several day the way to write in a csv file containing several computed columns just right to the next one. Even the unpleasant comments of some guys! I finally found how to do this. If someone need something similar:

First I save my data using `to_csv`:

```
data.to_csv('/Users/Computer/Desktop/Examples/data_new.csv', sep=',',mode='a', index=False)
```

after the file has been already generated with the headers, I remove the index that I don't need and I only call the function using at the end:

```
b = data
a = pd.read_csv('data_new.csv')
c = pd.concat ([a,b],axis=1, ignore_index=True)
c.to_csv('/Users/Computer/Desktop/Examples/data_new.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

As a result I got the CSV file desired and is possible to call the function the times that you want!